# jQuery to close submenu opened by mouseenter

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to mod pretty complex jQuery menu.

Originally, it opened on .click, but I want it to open on hover (.mouseenter).

I've made that change and you can see it in the main menu [here](http://globalgoodspartners.org/).

The issue is that any open sub stays open when I mouseenter a main link with no sub.

As you can see, there is a slideUpPanel() function. It works with .click but with .mouseenter, moving to a sub-less link does not fire slideUpPanel() b/c the sub-less link does not have the class .dropdown.

I've tried a few things to no avail.

I was hoping placing this code at the end -- before the mainMenu(); call -- would work

```
$(".main-menu .widescreen .nav-item > a").not(".dropdown").mouseenter(function() {
    slideUpPanel();
  });
```

But it does not do anything.

Here is the mainMenu(); function. The change from .click to .mouseenter is in the fifth line..

```
mainMenu = function() {
  var dropdown_panel, main_header, main_menu_dropdown_timer, slideUpPanel, startTimer, stopResetTimer;
  dropdown_panel = $(".main-menu-dropdown-panel .row");
  main_header = $(".template-index .main-header");
  HEADER.find(".main-menu .widescreen .dropdown > a").mouseenter(function() {
    var autoHeight, curHeight, dropdown, sub_nav;
    dropdown = $(this).parent();
    sub_nav = dropdown.find(".sub-nav .columns");
    if (PAGE.hasClass('template-index') && PAGE.hasClass('transparent-menu') && Modernizr.touch) {
      if ($('.main-header').hasClass('dropdown-open')) {
        if (dropdown.hasClass("active")) {
          startTimer();
        }
      } else {
        $('.main-header .bg').fadeIn();
      }
    }
    if (dropdown.hasClass("active")) {
      slideUpPanel();
    } else if ($('.main-header').hasClass('dropdown-open')) {
      dropdown_panel.find(".columns").animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, 200);
      dropdown_panel.find('.columns').remove();
      HEADER.find(".main-menu .dropdown").removeClass('active');
      dropdown.addClass("active");
      sub_nav.clone().appendTo(".main-menu-dropdown-panel .row");
      dropdown_panel.find(".columns").delay(200).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 200);
      curHeight = dropdown_panel.height();
      autoHeight = dropdown_panel.css('height', 'auto').outerHeight();
      dropdown_panel.height(curHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight
      }, 400);
    } else {
      dropdown_panel.find('.columns').remove();
      $('.main-header').addClass('dropdown-open');
      dropdown.addClass("active");
      sub_nav.clone().appendTo(".main-menu-dropdown-panel .row");
      dropdown_panel.slideDown(400, function() {
        return dropdown_panel.css("height", dropdown_panel.outerHeight());
      });
      dropdown_panel.find(".columns").delay(200).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 200);
    }
    return false;
  });
  slideUpPanel = function() {
    $('.main-header').removeClass('dropdown-open');
    dropdown_panel.find(".columns").animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 200);
    return dropdown_panel.delay(200).slideUp(function() {
      HEADER.find(".main-menu .dropdown").removeClass('active');
      dropdown_panel.find('.columns').remove();
      return dropdown_panel.css('height', 'auto');
    });
  };
  main_menu_dropdown_timer = '';
  if (Modernizr.touch === false) {
    $('.main-header').mouseenter(function() {
      if (PAGE.hasClass('template-index') && PAGE.hasClass('transparent-menu')) {
        $('.main-header .bg').fadeIn();
      }
      return stopResetTimer();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      if ($('.main-header').hasClass('dropdown-open')) {
        return startTimer();
      } else {
        if (PAGE.hasClass('template-index') && main_header.css("position") === "absolute") {
          return $('.main-header .bg').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  startTimer = function() {
    return main_menu_dropdown_timer = setTimeout((function() {
      slideUpPanel();
      if (PAGE.hasClass('template-index') && PAGE.hasClass('transparent-menu')) {
        return $('.main-header .bg').delay(300).fadeOut();
      }
    }), 500);
  };
  return stopResetTimer = function() {
    return clearTimeout(main_menu_dropdown_timer);
  };
};
mainMenu();
```

Thanks for any suggestions, and for helping me learn!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you...

```
$( ".main-menu .widescreen .dropdown > a" ).hover(
  function() {

    // show menu

  }, function() {

    // hide menu
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//I think this will help you

if(!$(".main-menu .widescreen .nav-item > a")
 .hasClass(".dropdown")){
 $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
     slideUpPanel();
   });
}
```